# What are some countries which implement dividend imputation system?

Tags: taxes, stocks, dividends

This is good to know because such countries encourages companies to pay higher dividends.

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dividendimputations.asp

Answer (score 3):

According to the article you posted, the countries with dividend imputation are Australia, Finland, Italy, Mexico, and New Zealand.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for more countries which may be missed out by the article.

Comment: @curious The wording in the article implies that it is a complete list. It says, "In any other country, corporate dividends are taxed twice."